The line with two origins is locally Euclidean, second-countable but not Hausdorff
I am trying to solve the following Problem in the book Introduction to smooth manifolds by Lee:

Let $X$ be the set of all points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$y=\pm 1$, and let $M$ be the quotien of $X$ by the equivalence
relation generated by $(x,-1) \sim (x,1)$ for all $x \neq 0$. Show
that $M$ is locally Euclidean and second countavle, but not Hausdorff.

First I just wrote down that the quotientopology was:
Quotientopology:
Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\sim$ an equivalence relation and define $Y:=X/ \sim$. The map $q: X \rightarrow Y$ maps elements $x \in X$ to their equivalence classes $[x] \in Y$. Thus the set $S \subset Y$ is open if $q^{-1}(S)$ is open.
Locally Euclidean:
We have to show that every point $m \in M$ has an open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.
Well, after drawing a picture of what $M$ should look like, the identity map $id: Y \rightarrow X$ should be a homeomorphism.
So let $m \in Y$ and $m$ not be the origin. Then a neighborhood of $m $ looks like $[(-\epsilon+m,\epsilon+m)]$
so the identity $id:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, bijective and its inverse is continuous.
So let $m \in Y$ then a neighborhood of $m$ at the "origin" should look like $[(-\epsilon,\epsilon)]$, so $id$ should also be a homeomorphism.
second countable:
Since $\mathbb{R}$ with it's topology induced by $|\cdot|$ is second countable. So the topology on $M$ is too.
One can see that by taking finite open cover of $X$,call it $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\cup_{C \in \mathcal{C}}q(C)$ is an open covering of $M$.
The last step would be to show that $M$ is not Hausdorff. But I do not really understand why it is not Hausdorff.
Questions:

Why is $M$ not Hausdorff (I assume we would get a problem in the "origin" but I can't write it down)?

Looking at my argumentation for "locally Euclidean", something seems a little bit off. Is my proof of the locally Euclidean part correct?



This answers your (first) question: Line with two origins. As for the second one,  "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.". Or look here

See also those many posts.
